# What're the advantages of using tflog package over log package for logging?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Context: I'm developing a TF Provider and I could see the latest ["Writing Log Output" doc](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/log/writing) from HashiCorp where they recommend using `tflog` package for logging.

That said, I can see TF Provider for GCP are still [using](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/main/google/resource_bigquery_reservation.go#L110) `log` package. What're the advantages of using `tflog` over `log`?

Comment: The document you linked to discusses the proposed benefits of using the wrapper module for logging. The Github page for the project also discusses a couple more proposed benefits. Different teams will make different decisions about dependency architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The *Structured Logging* section](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/log/writing#structured-logging) of the documentation you linked describes the authors' justification for recommending this different logging strategy:

> The `tflog` package uses structured logging, based on [go-hclog](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/go-hclog). Rather than writing logs as sentences with embedded variables and values, `tflog` takes a sentence describing the logging event and a set of variables to log. When variables are separate from the log description, you can use them to programmatically parse, filter, and search log output. This separation also allows other parts of the system to associate variables with downstream log output.

Although not mentioned explicitly as an advantage in the documentation, it does also mention that `tflog` has a notion of log levels, and there's no corresponding concept in [the standard library `log` package](https://pkg.go.dev/log) at the time of writing.

Given that, I would conclude that the two intended advantages of `tflog` over standard library `log` are:

- `tflog` uses a structured logging approach where the separate variables in the result are machine-parsable and therefore amenable to automated filtering via scripts.
- `tflog` associates a log level with each message, and the SDKs allow [customizing the log level for a particular execution](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/log/managing#log-levels) to control the amount of output.

I think getting any further context on this would require asking the authors of the SDKs, since this is a subjective design tradeoff rather than a situation where there is one clear correct answer.

I assume that some existing providers continue to use standard library `log` just because that code was written before `tflog` existed. `tflog` v0.2.0 (apparently the first publicly-published version) was released in December 2021, whereas big Terraform providers like the Google Cloud Platform provider have been under development for almost a decade before that.